# Cauchy product of two conditional convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Consider any conditional convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}=M$ and a Hilbert space $H$. Let $\{e_{n}\}$ be the orthonormal basis, the vector $(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n})e_{1}$ is well-defined and the inner product of this vector is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{*}_{n}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{m}=|M|^{2}$. This show the vector must belong to $H$. But the inner product is just the Cauchy product $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ with itself, and there exists conditional convergent series in which the Cauchy product with itself does not converge to $|M|^{2}. So what is wrong with the reasoning?

Answer (score 2):

The Cauchy product of $\sum a_n$ with $\sum b_n$ is the series $\sum c_n$ where $$c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}.$$

Here you're not dealing with $\sum c_n$ but just multiplying the numbers $\sum a_n$ with $\sum a^*_n$. So there is no issue at all regarding the convergence of $\sum c_n$.